# Missing left prompt elements for powerlevel9k

Tags: shell, terminal

noob here. I've installed iTerm2, zsh, oh-my-zsh and powerlevel9k. Afterwards I've installed Hyper3 and Spaceship prompt. Then I changed back to powerlevel9k. Can't remember if I did anything else worth mentioning on the way, but currently this is how my prompt looks like (red rectangles):

[image]

Notice the different between the prompts in the right and left pane. I wonder why it happened and if there's a way to change it back.

This is the code from my .zshrc file regarding powerlevel9k:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Powerlevel9k has half a dozen bugs affecting right prompt rendering. This is one of them: right prompt is supposed to be hidden if it would overlap left prompt, but powerlevel9k renders it on top of left prompt, obscuring a part of the latter in the process.

The easiest solution is to switch to [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/) -- a fast backward-compatible reimplementation where all known bugs are fixed and many extra features added.

1. Clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/powerlevel10k`
2. Set `ZSH_THEME=powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k` in your `~/.zshrc`.

This will fix the issue you are having and make your prompt 10 times faster.

Now you can also use extra features from powerlevel10k to improve your prompt. For example, instead of hiding right prompt when it would overlap left prompt, you might want to shorten the current directory instead. Here's how:

```bsh
# If directory is too long, shorten some of its segments to the shortest possible
# unique prefix. The shortened directory can be tab-completed to the original.
POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=truncate_to_unique
# Shorten directory only when prompt doesn't fit.
POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_MAX_LENGTH=
# Replace removed segment suffixes with this symbol.
POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DELIMITER=
```

You can see this in action in [this screencast](https://asciinema.org/a/258376).

You can also run `p10k configure` to configure your prompt through an interactive dialogue. It set up an even better directory truncation policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, you rock!